# How can I tell if a tf op has a gradient or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autodiff

I am interested in using a `SparseTensor` in tensorflow, however, I often get

> LookupError: No gradient defined for operation ...

Apparently gradient computation is not defined for many ops for sparse tensors. Are there any easy ways to check if an op has a gradient or not before actually writing and running my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `get_gradient_function` function in `tensorflow.python.framework.ops`. It accepts an op and returns a corresponding gradient op. Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import get_gradient_function

a = tf.add(1, 2, name="Add_these_numbers")
b = tf.multiply(a, 3, name='mult')

mult = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('mult')
print(get_gradient_function(mult))  # <function _MulGrad at 0x7fa29950dc80>

tf.stop_gradient(a, name='stop')
stop = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('stop')
print(get_gradient_function(stop))  # None
```